# Get collapsed menu on active link Jquery & Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I need to get collapsed the menu on click a link and that link will have a class named 'active'.

I got this only if i click the main link that match with the id and uri from url.
But on click a link that is inside of that link the menu collapse.

The main issue is that in jquery i cant get the alert and check if a class or id has been applied.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if($('#subcategoryactive').length){
        alert('Active');
    }
    if( $('.list-subgroup-item active').length )
{
     alert('Active');
}

</script>

<h4>Categories</h4>
          <div class="list-group categories">
          <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/products/catalog_list/' . $category['id'] ; ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $category['name']; ?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if($category['id'] == $this->uri->segment(3)){ echo 'in';}else{ echo 'out';} ?>">
            <?php foreach($category['sub_categories'] as $subcategory): ?>
            <div class="list-subgroups">
              <a id="subcategory<?php if($subcategory['id'] == $this->uri->segment(3)){ echo 'active';} ?>" href="<?php echo $subcategory['id']; ?>"  class="list-subgroup-item <?php if($subcategory['id'] == $this->uri->segment(3)){ echo 'active';} ?>"><?php echo $subcategory['name']; ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php //endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first things you need to wrap your jquery codes using the dom ready event and use the `on` method try changing the jquery codes to the following and let me know

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ // add this 
    $('div.list-group').on('click', 'a.active', function(){
        //if($('#subcategoryactive').length) {
        //    alert('Active');
        //}
        //if( $('.list-subgroup-item active').length ) {
            alert('Active');
        //}
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: That's it, it uncollapse all menus and keep uncollapsed, thx Moes